# How to stay with "." at decimal ToString after culture changes

Tags: c#, localization, uiculture

I have a web site with different languages. Inside a model, I have the following member declaration:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.GlobalResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "awr1")]
[Range(typeof(decimal), "0.00100001", "10000", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.GlobalResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "TotalMoneyMinMaxValidation")]
public decimal TotalMoney { get; set; }
```

When I change the UI culture to `ru-RU`, I get the following error:

> 0.00100001 is not a valid value for Decimal.

How can I keep my culture info and UI as `ru-RU` but have all decimals be a period(.) instead of a comma(,)?

Here's what I've tried:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
```

not working...

Answer (score 1):

There is no precise workaround for this issue since the `RangeAttribute` is converted using the run-time culture.  You need to either accept a loss of precision using doubles:

```
[Range(0.01, 10000)]
```

or give up on using the `RangeAttribute` entirely.

See [this link](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2009/07/09/191.aspx).